# Maven <mirror> tag, meaning of external:* parameter

Tags: maven, repository, maven-2, maven-3, mirroring

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal-repository</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
      <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
      <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

The official documentation, about the meaning of the `external:*` parameter within a `<mirrorOf>` tag, says that:

> matches all repositories except those using localhost or file based
>   repositories. This is used in conjunction with a repository manager
>   when you want to exclude redirecting repositories that are defined for
>   Integration Testing.

Within this context, my question are:

- What does it mean that a repository uses localhost?
- What does it mean that repository is file-based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - What does it mean that a repository uses localhost?

Simply that the host of the URL used in any repository declaration is not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. For example, a repository whose URL is declared as:

```
<repository>
  <id>my-repo</id>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/repo</url> <!-- or http://127.0.0.1:8080/repo -->
</repository>
```

it will not be considered by the `external:*` mirror, because its host is `localhost`. This could be the case, for example, if you have an artifact manager hosted on the same machine, and you're working locally (so there is no need for a proxy).

> - What does it mean that repository is file-based?

That the protocol of the URL of the repository is `file`. For example, a repository whose URL is declared as:

```
<repository>
  <id>my-repo</id>
  <url>file:///C:\my-repo</url>
</repository>
```

would be a file-based repository. The artifacts will be searched inside the folder `C:\my-repo`, like if it were a usual remote repository. This is useful if you want to set-up a remote repository for testing purposes (i.e. no artifact managers, just working with folders, possibly on another drive). In this case, there is no need for a proxy as well, and `external:*` will not consider it.

For reference, the code for `external:*` performs [exactly those checks](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/bridge/MavenRepositorySystem.java#L712-L725).